# Perf branch filter for both user and kernel data

Tags: perf

For the following per command

```
perf record -e cycles -j any -a -o perf.data -p 3696
```

I would like to record both user and kernel data. I know that the modifier `:uk` is valid for `cycles`, but I don't know if I have to apply `,uk` for the `-j` option. According to the manual

> ```
> -j, --branch-filter 
>     any: any type of branches 
>     u: only when the branch target is at the user level 
>     k: only when the branch target is in the kernel 
>     hv: only when the target is at the hypervisor level
> ```

So, for use data, I typically run `perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data -p 3696`. However, this time

```
perf record -e cycles:uk -j any,uk -a -o perf.data -p 3696
```

fails with unknown branch filter.

Is it fine to just use `-j any` for user and kernel data?

Comment: Did you try `-j any`?  Does it not default to user + kernel?

Comment: I used that, but don't know how to verify that. How can I check if both kernel and user are included in the data file?

Comment: By using it however you were planning on doing so (e.g. `perf report`), and see seeing if the branch info you want is there for both user and kernel samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Using `any` means it will sample any 'type' of taken branches (eg. function call/function return/indirect branches etc.).

To record both `user` and `kernel` data, you should run `perf record` like this -

```
perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u,k -a -o perf.data -p <PID>
```

Also, you need not use both `-a` and the `-p <PID>` options together, in such a case `-p <PID>` switch overrides the `-a` option.